# Finding Controls in WPF DataGrid? Using Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

[image]I am automating the WPF application using coded UI, I am trying to find a row in Data Grid which is unable to find the control, when i ask my developer about the control hierarchy, they said that they put another Data Grid with in the Data Grid. When i record the control which is unable to find the control, Can any one help me thankyou.

After clicking the first toggle button second row will display, actually it is not second row, with in that row only Data Grid is added. This is my code..

```
 WpfCustom custDetaPre = new WpfCustom(rowGrid);
      custDetaPre.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCustom.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.DataGridDetailsPresenter");
      //custDetaPre.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
      custDetaPre.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCustom.PropertyNames.TechnologyName, "UIA");
```

When i try to record the second toggle button it is with in the above custom control, with in this custom control data grid is placed.

this is my total code :

```
 WpfTable tableGrid = new WpfTable(DashboarWindow);
 tableGrid.SearchProperties.Add(WpfTable.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.DataGrid");  
  tableGrid.Find();
```

The above code for finding the Data grid in the form.

```
WpfRow rowGrid = new WpfRow(tableGrid);
rowGrid.SearchProperties.Add(WpfRow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.DataGridRow");
```

The above code is row of the data grid

```
 WpfCell celGrid = new WpfCell(rowGrid);
 celGrid.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.DataGridCell");
```

the above code is first row and first cell in the data grid

```
 WpfToggleButton toglButtonShowall = new WpfToggleButton(celGrid);
      toglButtonShowall.SearchProperties.Add(WpfToggleButton.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "ShowDetails");
      Mouse.Click(toglButtonShowall);
```

the above code is first toggle button, when i click on this (toggle), the second row will display, (second toggle button ) but this is not second row, this is a another data grid within the row. to find the second data grid one custom control is there with in this custom control only this second grid is exists. but i am trying to find this custom control i am getting the exception that is control can not found, the code for custom control is like below.

```
 WpfCustom custDetaPre = new WpfCustom(rowGrid);
 custDetaPre.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCustom.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.DataGridDetailsPresenter");
 custDetaPre.DrawHighlight();
```

from the above code where i am getting the exception. 
     custDetaPre.Drawhighlight()

Comment: In Data Grid Row it contain Toggle Button

Comment: Coded UI cannot see into custom controls unless that custom control includes support for MSAA or UIA. The same support that is needed to allow screen readers etc as used by people with sight problems.

Comment: i attached the screen shot of my Data Grid, here in the first toggle button i am able to access, but second toggle button is unable to trace.

Comment: Thank you for reply @Adrian, it is custom control only, but Technology Name is UIA.

Comment: When you use the "crosshairs" tool in the Coded UI recorder to view the controls, what does it show? Can it find the innermost controls on the screen? Can it draw a box around just the `4` or the `65` on the bottom line shown in the screenshot? If it can then generate an assert on that value (in a sandbox project if necessary) and copy the relevant bits of code into your test. If it cannot then the custom controls do not support enough of MSAA or UIA.

Comment: Yes, it shows innermost controls, even toggle button properties able to see when i place cross hair tool, but the same when i try to find the toggle button, it is unable to access. it is throwing error at Custom Controls, like my Custom controls "custDetaPre" i.e., "Uia.DataGridDetailsPresenter"

Comment: when i try to find toggle button, through hand code, it is throwing error at custom control , with in that custom control second Data Grid is exists with in that data grid only this second toggle button exists

Comment: So record and generate a test. Make it work, then copy the relevant bits into your hand-coded test. There are numerous Q&As here and on other sites about debugging Coded UI tests and getting them to work. Without a [mcve] I think you are unlikely to get much better help here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144448/discussion-between-surya-sasidhar-and-adrianhhh).

Comment: See my comments in chat.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll want to specify an explicit `Row` and `Column` index.
Add the row index to both the `WpfRow` and `WpfCell` and a column index to the `WpfCell`
From your screen shot, you are at least failing to qualify the row since you have 2 rows. you may not need the column index as long as you don't have multiple toggle buttons in a row.

As is, if you call `rowGrid.FindMatchingControls()` after setting the search params, you should return two controls

From your comments....

```
WpfRow rowGrid = new WpfRow(tableGrid); 
rowGrid.SearchProperties.Add(WpfRow.PropertyNames.RowIndex , "0");
WpfCell celDeffe = new WpfCell(rowGrid); 
celDeffe.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.RowIndex‌​, "0"); 
celDeffe.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIn‌​dex, "0");
WpfToggleButton toglButtonShowall = new WpfToggleButton(celGrid);
toglButtonShowall.SearchProperties.Add(WpfToggleButton.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "ShowDetails");
Mouse.Click(toglButtonShowall);
```

I would expect the above to work for you

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for reply, i will try and let you know.

Comment: WpfTable tableGrid = new WpfTable(DashWindow.DashItemCustom.DashTabList.PIPrismPrismExtensioTabPage);
 tableGrid.SearchProperties.Add(WpfTable.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Uia.DataGrid");
 tableGrid.Find();

Comment: WpfRow rowGrid = new WpfRow(tableGrid);         
         rowGrid.SearchProperties.Add(WpfRow.PropertyNames.RowIndex , "0");

Comment: WpfCell celDeffe = new WpfCell(rowGrid);
          celDeffe.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.RowIndex, "0");
          celDeffe.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex, "0");
var count = celDeffe.FindMatchingControls().Count;

Comment: From the screen shot, the second toggle button is not in second row, it is in different data grid,  I mean data grid in another data grid that is first toggle button in one data grid and second toggle button in in second data grid , which is in first data grid  row.

Comment: it is showing only one row, I mean one count, I put UITestControlCollection coll = rowGrid.FindMatchingControls();  and

Comment: UITestControlCollection colec = rowGrid.GetChildren(); it is showing only 8 child controls that is Header control and remaining 7 or WpfCells i check their values also.